# MongoDB C++ driver not throwing connection error

Tags: c++, mongodb, exception, try-catch

Here is my code-

```
DBClientBase *conn = NULL;
string err_msg;
ConnectionString cs = ConnectionString::parse(connString, err_msg);

if (!cs.isValid()) {
   throw "bad: " + err_msg;
}

try {
  conn = cs.connect(err_msg);
}
catch (DBException &e) {
   cout << "caught " << err_msg << endl;
   return 1;
}

if (!conn) {
   cout << "Unable to connect to DB" << endl;
   return 1;
}
```

I would expect MongoDB to throw exception in case DB is not reachable. However, I am finding that  `if (!conn)` is getting satisfied.

Why

```
catch (DBException &e) {
   cout << "caught " << err_msg << endl;
   return 1;
}
```

block isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the current trunk source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/client/dbclient.cpp#L58), `ConnectionString::connect` only seems to throw an exception when the string itself was invalid (and you already know that it was not, from your first conditional statement).

It just returns a NULL pointer and sets `errMsg` in all other cases.

In your defence, I couldn't find this documented anywhere at all; [a very basic example of `connect`](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_connection_string.html) was all I could locate.

```
string err_msg;
ConnectionString cs = ConnectionString::parse(connString, err_msg);

if (!cs.isValid()) {
   throw "bad: " + err_msg;
}

DBClientBase* conn = cs.connect(err_msg);

if (!conn) {
   cout << "Unable to connect to DB: " << err_msg << endl;
   return 1;
}
```